# Detecting Source Application for Launch Depracated? Aternatives?

Tags: swift, xcode, sharing

I am trying to detect if another application has launched my app in order to launch a different view to accept a pdf being passed to it. It appears that LaunchOptionsKey can be used in the AppDelegate, but the following code dosn't seem to work. Can anyone tell me if I'm using the code wrong or if there are alternatives. Most references use the sourceApplication to do this, but I read claims that is was depracated in 2019, yet apple still has it in their documentation?  Also I notice that switching launch views only works in the SceneDelegate instead of the AppDelegate. Apparently this is also a recent change?

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  print("finished launching")
    
    if launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.sourceApplication] != nil {
        print("Launched by another app")
        startVC = "addFile"
    } else {
        print("source app not identified")
    }

    return true
}

class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    
    print("Scene: finished launching")
      //self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds) // black sreen
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    if startVC == "addFile" {
        let initialVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "addFile") as! addFileViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialVc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()       
    }
    if startVC == "home" {
        let initialVc = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:  "home") as! FirstController
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialVc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
   guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the change to using SceneDelegate came in with ios 13.  All the usual startup window management / programatic setting up of the initial view controller was moved to it.

Comment: Any comment on the  LaunchOptionsKey.sourceApplication usage? It doesn't seem to pickup when started by using another app share event.

Comment: Never really used it, but II thought this key was just for apps in your team / app group, rather than third party apps?

Comment: Check out the docs.   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/launchoptionskey/1623064-sourceapplication